# How to get records that are less than n minutes?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the records from php that every row have following table:

[created_at] => 2022-10-15 08:17:52

I want get record that are created last minute.
for that i my php file:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_billing_details WHERE DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) >= NOW();
```

but it returning the same row even after it is more than 1 minute old,
I dont able to understand what is happening.

Comment: Instead of the hack and/or workaround `DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) >= NOW();` - calculate the date for 1 minute ago in PHP, then pass it as simple as: ```... `created_at` >= $myOneMinuteAgoVariable;"```

Comment: Even if you fix the hack, what happens the day you want to support a different SQL-system (beside `MySQL`)? repeating same effort.

Comment: like how? i want to get records of last minute so what should my php variable looks like

Comment: @Top-Master - I would argue that if they should do it in PHP v MySQL depends on which server it was that set the date in the first place (and are on different servers.) If the MySQL server set the date (something like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), it's better to do it in MySQL (since the time on the servers _can_ differ). Regarding _"what happens the day you want to support a different SQL-system"_ I have to say that after more than 2 decades as a developer, I've never actually seen that happen. Not without a complete rewrite of the code as well.

Comment: Workaround the time-conflicts that @M.Eriksson mentioned by setting a standard time-zone in `MySQL`, and ensure same time and time-zone are used in PHP server as well (even if they are not different servers, this helps in future).

Comment: This may seem like a lot for a beginner, but better learn these now, instead of getting fired later.

Comment: Best way to support multiple SQL-systems is to use a framework which does that already, for example, use `Laravel` like:
```$collection = CustomerBillingDetail::query()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMinute())->get();```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need >= NOW(). the interval will automatically handle the time interval. use something like

```
 SELECT *
FROM `customer_billing_details`
WHERE `created_at` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

Change 5 minutes to 1 or 2 according to your needs.